# Cannot update project with composer

Tags: composer-php

I pushed my package medyes/ebay-api on github.

When I tried to download it on another project with composer I have an error:

Command composer:

```
composer require medyes/ebay-api:dev-master
```

The error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package medyes/ebay-api at any version for your
>   minimum-stability (dev). Check the package spelling or your minimum
>   -stability

this is the composer.json of medyes/ebay-api package 
[composer.json](https://github.com/medyes/ebay-api/blob/master/composer.json)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using branches - especially when the project you are about to include offers tagged versions.

```
composer require medyes/ebay-api:~0.1
```

This will update this package until version 1.0 comes out (which would not be installed, because that major release number change it is considered incompatible according to semantic versioning) every time a newer, installable version exists and you run `composer update`.